# Mongodb autosharding vs. authentication

Tags: authentication, mongodb, sharding

Long time lurker, first time poster, please bear with me.

I'm trying to set up a sharded, secure Mongodb environment.  I would like to make use of Mongo's autosharding capability, since I'm sort of new to databases and on a tight schedule.

It seems that autosharding only applies to individual collections (tables), but I don't want users to have access to the entire collection.  Further, mongoDB only allows authentication into databases, so once authenticated, a user can see 1) every collection in the db and 2) all data within each collection.  So, as far as I can tell, I can either have autosharding and no authentication, or manual sharding and authentication.

I would like the best of both worlds, that is: autosharding and authentication.  Is this possible?  If not, how should I go about manual sharding in MongoDB?

A simplified use case of this system: collection 'Users' has data on every user.  I want to authenticate user X so that X can only see X's data in the User's collection.  And Users is distributed across multiple servers partitioned (sharded) by user_name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDb doesn't have authentication like traditional SQL databases. In fact if you read the manual its recommended that you use a secured environment instead of using authentication. Any access control to your data would be implemented within your application.

Even with traditional SQL, access isnt control by row. Thats usually something implemented at the application level based on some sort of key within the data.

Comment: thanks datasage.  I think I'm going to try out a hybrid system of manually partitioning by user, so that each user has their own db, and then sharding each userdb.collection.  I probably will also implement some kind of security through a client to the whole system.